# Regarding TestNG Execution

Tags: testng

Highlevel:
I have one @Test method A with assert statements and assertAll() at the end.
Inside this method A, I'm calling another method B having assert statements and assertAll() at the end.

Current Issue:
If any assert statement fails in the called method B, I can see assertion errors in the console, which is good.
But the remaining statements in the calling method A are not getting executed.

Example...

```
public class class1 
{
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception
    {
    class2 obj = new class2();
    SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
    sassert.assertNotNull("123", "Failed, It is null");
    obj.test2();
    sassert.assertNotNull("3456", "Failed, It is null");            
    sassert.assertAll();

    }

}

public class class2 
{

    public void test2() throws Exception
    {

    SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
    sassert.assertNotNull("111", "Failed, It is null");
    sassert.assertNotNull("222", "Failed, It is null");         
    sassert.assertAll();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of where you are invoking `assertAll()`, this method call runs through all the assertions that were collected via `assertXXX()` methods. So what you are seeing is an expected behavior.

So if your `class2.test2()` is **NOT** an `@Test` method, then you can refactor your code to look like below :

```java
public class class1 {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
        class2 obj = new class2(sassert);
        sassert.assertNotNull("123", "Failed, It is null");obj.test2();
        sassert.assertNotNull("3456", "Failed, It is null");            
        sassert.assertAll();
    }
}

public class class2 {
    public void test2(SoftAssert sassert) throws Exception {
        sassert.assertNotNull("111", "Failed, It is null");
        sassert.assertNotNull("222", "Failed, It is null");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above example, `class2.test2()` accepts a `SoftAssert` object upon which it adds up more assertions but doesn't run through the assertions yet. It would be the responsibility of the invoker of `class2.test2()` to do that.